# Conditional List Filters

Tags: web-part, list-view, filter, web

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to create a filter that I need for a list I've made. I need to filter a certain column based on the current user.

For example, if the current user is "John Doe", I only want to show items in the list where Shift = "A". If the current user is "Jane Doe", I only want to show items in the list where Shift = "B".

The only filters I have found are ones where the column matches the current user exactly. I don't know how to incorporate this third variable in getting my filter to work.

Thanks.

Comment: could you use url parameters in combination with some other logic to direct the person to the correct url?

Comment: Right now my list is being displayed on a web page as a web part. Is there a way to use url parameters when the list is a web part?

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of users in filters.  This will get to be a pain to manage when new users are added.

I would suggest creating 2 lists:  ShiftA and ShiftB.  Then create 2 SharePoint permission groups ShiftAGroup and ShiftBGroup that can view their own list only.

Then on the web part page you place both lists out there.  You as the owner/admin will see both lists, but members of ShiftAGroup will only see the list items from ShiftA.  Likewise, members from ShiftBGroup will only see list items from ShiftB.

One problem with the view/filter approach is that once you drop the web part on the page, if you update your view definition, you have to go back to the web part page and re-drop it for the update to take place.  This will be often the more users you want to add to the view filter.

With the Permission group approach, you only need to add/remove users from the group and your solution will continue to work fine.

Comment: This is not quite what I'm looking for. My page is going to have 3 separate lists on it, so making a new list for each version is going to become very troublesome.

The closest I got was creating a choice filter where the user can select the shift that they need to see. However, is there a way to set a custom default value based on the user? Or, is there a way to save the choice filter so the user does not need to reenter it every session?

Comment: A list per shift, not a list per version.  I still recommend permission groups.  It will trim automatically and you only need to maintain the permission group membership.  Otherwise I suggest you better explain your problem with more detail above.

Comment: I have three lists that are going to be displayed on a web page (List1, List2, List3). All of these lists have a column called Shift. Ideally, I would have a filter that I can put on the web page that will filter all three of these lists to show information for the correct shift. With your suggestion, it sounds like I would need 6 different lists to accomplish what I am trying to make. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: I think I understand.  The 3 lists have items that concern each shift.  In this case, You wouldn't need 6 lists.  3 lists and 3 permission groups.  Then for each item you add to the list you would need to permission to a group.  This is a subtle  twist to my original answer but much simpler approach than views with user filters.  Or wait for a better answer.